# Finding the next instance of an element, regardless of relationship, using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on the error messaging for my form and I am trying to figure out how to display the errors using one function. Unfortunately, the error message element's relationship to the field varies throughout my form. In some instances, it will be this:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" />
    <div class="error">Please enter your first name.</div>
</div>
```

In which case, I can use `$(this).next.show();` in order to display the error message.

However, in other instances, my fields are structured like this:

```
<div id="variants">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
        <label><input type="radio" name="variant" value="red">Red</label><br/>
        <label><input type="radio" name="variant" value="green">Green</label><br/>
        <label><input type="radio" name="variant" value="blue">Blue</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
        <label><input type="radio" name="variant" value="yellow">Yellow</label><br/>
        <label><input type="radio" name="variant" value="brown">Brown</label><br/>
        <label><input type="radio" name="variant" value="orange">Orange</label>
    </div>
    <div class="error">Please select a product variant.</div>
</div>
```

In this example, the above jQuery selector will not work since the `.error` element is the sibling of the parent of the input, instead of a direct sibling of the input.

My question is, is there any way to select the next closest instance of an element regardless of the relationship to the element it is being compared to? I was looking into `.closest()` but haven't been able to get it working.

Thanks!

Comment: If all the containing divs had a common class it'd be simple.

Comment: You should use id instead of class selectors.  You need to structure you elemets and layout properly.  Like for error you can put id with prefix or suffix like id="firstname_error" so in you jquery you just say jquery('#<id of element>_error').show()

Comment: @Andrex that is a great suggestion and a bit cleaner way of approaching this issue, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to effectively search up and down at each level of the hierarchy.

```
$(this).parents().has('.error').first().find('.error');
```

This will check each parent in turn seeing when one has an error class, return the closest, then find the descendant error.

You might also be able to use something like this:

```
$(this).closest(':has(.error)').find('.error');
```

Here is a JSFiddle showing both working (to stop all the whining): http://jsfiddle.net/u37twowx/1/ :)

**You will note this solution does not required a class to be added in the hierarchy.**

Comment: how parent will find the error class, it is not parent of it?

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad: `has` will see if it has the descendant. `find` will find it. What's your point? :)

Comment: `closest()` finds parent element with some criteria, i am not getting how you are doing it..:)

Comment: This would not work well if I had more than one `.error` divs inside the same container...

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad: I am sorry you do not get it. `has` checks all descendants of the parents. Closest stops at the first match. try it.

Comment: @cSalazar: When is there more than one error in a single div? If there are they probably want them all.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad `parents()` goes up and selects all ancestors of the current element like `.closest()` - except `.closest()` also checks itself

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: That's a pretty bold assumption. Then again, the OP didn't specify whether or not there would be more than one .error element to begin with (although they did refer to it in singular).

Comment: i know `closest()` stops @TrueBlueAussie would you mind explaining it or making a fiddle of your code

Comment: i am not getting your second statement, first one is ok, i got it

Comment: @user13286: They both work, as `parents()` works in parent, grandparent order, but the second is more efficient (and more readable).

Comment: @EhsanSajjad `.parents()` = get all ancestors of element -- `.has('.error')` = filter(only keep ones that has descendant .error elements) -- `.first()` = get the closest one to the element(because parents goes up the tree the closest one will be the first one) -- `.find('.error')` = find the .error element

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Yep, both worked great, thank you again!

Answer (score 3):

Use a common class for each input element container div and target the error div using `closest()` and `find()`.

For Example:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 element">
    <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" />
    <div class="error">Please enter your first name.</div>
</div>

<div id="variants" class="element">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
        <label><input type="radio" name="variant" value="red">Red</label><br/>
        <label><input type="radio" name="variant" value="green">Green</label><br/>
        <label><input type="radio" name="variant" value="blue">Blue</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
        <label><input type="radio" name="variant" value="yellow">Yellow</label><br/>
        <label><input type="radio" name="variant" value="brown">Brown</label><br/>
        <label><input type="radio" name="variant" value="orange">Orange</label>
    </div>
    <div class="error">Please select a product variant.</div>
</div>
```

and now with jquery:

```
$(this).closest(".element").find(".error").show();
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I tested this and it worked great.

Answer (score 1):

Something that I have been using for quiet sometime is using the `:after` pseudo class, and then adding that class to the element that is receiving the error.

There are multiple ways to do it, especially if you want a custom message.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" />
```

**CSS**

```
input.error:after, input.error::after {
    content: '';
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 20px;
    background: red;
    color: white;
}

#first_name.error:after, #first_name.error:after {
    content: 'Please input first name.';
}

#last_name.error:after, #last_name.error:after {
    content: 'Please input last name.';
}
.
.
.
```

**jQuery**

```
$('input').keypress(function(){
    if(/*Conditional*/){
        $(this).addClass('error');
    }
});
```

This is a simple jQuery function, you just have to set it up to handle the error's accordingly.

Comment: `::after` is a pseudo-element, not a pseudo-class. The `::` is there specifically to make that distinction, the way it's being used here shows a lack of understanding of its significance. The `:` syntax is allowed for backwards compatibility; it is completely redundant to specify both of them together. Pick one and go with that.

Comment: @BoltClock the redundancy is on purpose, because I have had issues in Chrome when using `:` as opposed to `::`. If you think my knowledge is lacking, how about providing me with something to read up on it? instead of being nonconstructive.

Comment: I've never heard of such an issue, but knowing Chrome, I can't say I'm surprised. You should have explained that in your answer, because you should *never* have to include both syntaxes otherwise (and especially not in the same rule, because then *IE8* will correctly ignore them by spec). Here's a link, but it doesn't say anything that I haven't already stated in my comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#pseudo-elements